# Implementing 3D movement forces

Tags: objective-c, math, 3d

I have a 3D object moving and I need to be able to apply forces to it such as gravity. In 2D, I would simply store its movement in dx and dy, but since this is in 3D, I am using a `Vector3D direction` and a `float speed`. How can I determine how much to rotate the direction and change the speed when by using something like `applyForce(Vector3D force)`?

Comment: As DSM says, applying forces works more naturally with a `Vector3D velocity`.  You can get absolute speed from a 3D velocity by using the usual Euclidean length computation: `sqrt(x^2+y^2+z^2)`.

Answer (score 1):

Newton's second law gives that the acceleration is proportional to the force applied. Thus, a really simple method is forward integration, e.g. (pseudocode for compactness)

```
class Object {
   Vector3D position;
   Vector3D velocity;
   float mass;

   updatePhysics(Vector3D force, float dt) {
      velocity += (1.0/mass) * force * dt;
      position += velocity * dt;
   }
}
```

Of course, in real life there are problems with for example numeric instability and the choice of time delta. I did not understand from your question if you try to perform some one-shot calculation or if this is for a 3D game. If the latter, I suggest looking into a physics library such as Bullet Physics, you will get a lot for free.

Comment: Typo in your equation: `F = ma`, so `a = dv/dt = F/m`, and `dv ~ (F/m) * dt.`